# How to remove/skip empty lines from option select list

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using angular, building a dropdown with some options.  I am trying to set only these values that in needed for Employer ( -> Employees.. ) .. the idea itself works, but I don't understand how to remove empty lines .. these are the values that do not belong to the Employer, they are created due to NgFor

HTML:

```
     <br>
    <b>EmployeeName</b>
    <br>
    <select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="EmployeeName">
        <option *ngFor="let bookItem of bookList" [value]="bookItem.EmployeeName">
            <b  *ngIf="bookItem.EmployerName===namee">
               {{bookItem.EmployeeName}}
            </b> 
        </option>
    </select>

<b>EmployeeName</b>
    <br><select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="EmployeeName">
        <option *ngFor="let bookItem of bookList" [value]="bookItem.EmployeeName">
            <b  *ngIf="bookItem.EmployerName===namee">
               {{bookItem.EmployeeName}}
            </b> 
        </option>
    </select>
```

TS:

```
constructor(private service:SharedService, private datePipe: DatePipe) {
this.service.getEmployerList().subscribe(data => {
  this.bookList2 = data;
 this.service.getEmployeeList().subscribe(data => {
this.bookList = data;



onChangeEvent(event: any) `{
this.namee = event.target.value;}
```

My FrontEnd looks like::
[Employee of specific Employer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnetF.png)

I need to remove these blanks :D

Comment: `let bookItem of bookList.filter(d=>d.EmployerName===namee)` instead of `let bookItem of bookList`

Comment: yes it would be great, but for some reason it gives errors and does not accept this method

Comment: maybe i need to download additional packages/ dependencies for it ?

Comment: can you check the value of `namee` variable

Comment: No, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a javacsript array prototype

Comment: <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="EmployerName" (change)="namee = onChangeEvent($event)">
            <option *ngFor="let bookItem of bookList2" [value]="bookItem.EmployerName">
               <b>{{bookItem.EmployerName}}</b> 
            </option>
        </select>

Comment: name variable is changing, after changing Employeer Dropdown

Comment: EmployerName dropdown is responsible for onChangeEvent method call

Comment: after which the value Name is changes

Comment: Change `let bookItem of bookList` to `let bookItem of getbookList()`

Comment: Add a new function like `getbookList () { reutrn this.bookList.filter(d=>d.EmployerName===this.namee) }`

Comment: .. Did All .. And Little Improve ::: 

getbookList () { 
  return this.bookList.filter((d: { EmployerName: string; })=>d.EmployerName===this.namee)
 }

Now Another Error

` error TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'. `

5         <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="EmployerName" (change)="namee = onChangeEvent($event)">

Comment: what's the type for your variable `bookList`?

Comment: bookList: any = [];

Comment: then you dont need `((d: { EmployerName: string })=>d...)` as the type of `d` is implecitely of `any` type. you will have to use it like `d['EmployerName`] === this.namee`

Comment: also fixed   namee : any; .. 
now Service is working ... 
But FrontEnd don't showing Employees

Comment: try a `console.log(this.namee)` inside the function

Comment: Brother .. Fixed , from 
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="EmployerName" (change)="namee = onChangeEvent($event)">

To 

<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="EmployerName" (change)="onChangeEvent($event)">


It's Working ... Thank You very much  !!! :))))

Comment: Just removed this (change)="namee = onChangeEvent($event)" ... namee = ... from you know ..  =D

Comment: console.log(this.namee) it's a big helper :)

Comment: Glad that it helped

Comment: You don't need to use console.log, just use a javascript debugger like the one built into Chrome or atom or VS code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Folks ^^ this worked for me :

```
<select
          formControlName="type" id="type"
        >
          <option [selected]=true [disabled]="true" value=""  >Choose feedback type</option>
          <option *ngFor="let feedBackType of feedbackList" [value]="feedBackType">
            {{feedBackType }}
          </option>
        </select>
```

add this to css file :

```
select > option[value=""] {
  display: none;
}
```